# Marklogic : Multiple XML files created on document on importing a csv. How to get root Document URI path?

Tags: xml, database, csv, xquery, marklogic

I am new to Marklogic, I tried to import my CSV files of 100k records to Marklogic and after import, I found it gets imported to Documents Database by default. Also, I found for each records, I see a XML file generated in the database with incremental number appended to the "documentUri" that I mentioned while importing. For Example: documentUri_1.xml. I understands multiple xml files are created inorder to read the data in a distributed manner.

> Question:
>   1. How to get the root document URI for this document? which has multiple xml files?
>   Question: 2. How do i import the same CSV file to a different database?
>   Question: 3. When I use xquery to list all documents in the database, I am getting all the all xml files URI rather just the dummy.xml uri? How do I achieve this?

Note: I was using following command to import:

```
mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path dummy.csv -mode local -input_file_type delimited_text -uri_id 'dummy.xml'
```

Can you someone help me on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1) There is no such thing as a "root document".  Every document stands on its own.  But you can group documents together by collection (see below).

Question 2) Use the [***-database***](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_23879) mlcp option.

Question 3) I think you're looking for the mlcp option [***-filename_as_collection***](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mlcp/import#id_23879).  This will allow you to find documents by a collection named after the file.  For example, in XQuery:

```
collection("dummy.csv")
```

Comment: thank you for helping me on this. I tried using collection("dummy.csv") and i received "your query returned an empty sequence". the reason i wanted to get the collection of files is to filter the dummy.csv documents from the other set of documents that I inserted to the database. Any thoughts..

Comment: @mani Since this answers the question you asked, you should mark it as accepted and ask another question related to the next issue.

Comment: sure. But the answer doesn't provide the required result.  collection("dummy.csv") provides empty results. Is there a different command to work on?

Answer (score 1):

The answer does not work because your sample did not include the recommended command option

```
 -filename_as_collection
```

Not to be found in:

```
mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path dummy.csv -mode local -input_file_type delimited_text -uri_id 'dummy.xml'
```

Comment: got it thanks. let me try to reimport it to a new database. thanks much,

Comment: I tried this following command.. mlcp.bat import -host localhost -port 8000 -username admin -password admin -input_file_path earthquakes.csv -mode local -filename_as_collection "dummy.csv" -database "dummyDB" -input_file_type delimited_text -delimited_root_name profile -delimited_uri_id id -output_uri_suffix _earthquake.xml
as you mentioned. The document go loaded to new database. But I still return empty on calling collection("dummy.csv"). Can you assist me on what I am missing. @DALDEI