# How to pass document uri & database name to marklogic spark connector?

Tags: java, apache-spark, marklogic, connector, bigdata

I am trying this marklogic spark connector tutorial. 
https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/marklogic-spark-example
I was able to execute this. What I found is, it picks the documents database by default.

Question is:

Given code looks like this:

```
JavaPairRDD<DocumentURI, MarkLogicNode> mlRDD = context.newAPIHadoopRDD( hdConf, Configuration DocumentInputFormat.class, InputFormat DocumentURI.class, Key Class MarkLogicNode.class, Value Class );
```

I was wondering how I can pass the specific Document URI and Database to just get a specific document in a database.
For Example;
Documents database with xml files created on importing a csv file. Mentioned below: [Marklogic : Multiple XML files created on document on importing a csv. How to get root Document URI path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698593/marklogic-multiple-xml-files-created-on-document-on-importing-a-csv-how-to-ge)
Can some one share a sample code on how to pass the document URI and database name as parameters?

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to documentation for MarkLogic Connector for Hadoop, specifically 
[Input Configuration Properties](http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/input#id_16606) - You will find the property *mapreduce.marklogic.input.documentselector* which takes the XQuery path expression that allows you to select sepcific documents from the database.

Answer (score 0):

The sample uses The Hadoop Connector.

Using MarkLogic 8, I believe you can set the database like this: com.marklogic.output.databasename in the job configuration.

> http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/mapreduce/quickstart#id_38329

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I did see that it was using hadoop connector. I have tried it. But I am trying to achieve is,just read a specific document from a specific database. When i loaded a dummy.csv file of 1000 records, it created 100 xml files in the documents database with my other sample xml files. I just wanted to read the specific dummy.csv xml files from dcoument database. The current code retrives all documents from documents database by default. Trying to see where to modify my code. Much appreciate your help on this.